# WPF ListBox Auto Width Changes Incorrectly When DataTemplate Has Visibility Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a ListBox docked to the left of a window whose width should size to it's contents. When I scroll the listbox, it's width wobbles and becomes wider than it should be. Essentially what I think is happening is that the ListBox calculates the size of all it's children to determine it's own size, but only seems to evaluate visibility bindings for controls that are actually on the screen (presumably for performance reasons). The result is that it calculates the size of it's off-screen children incorrectly, reserving space for hidden controls.

If there are fewer items in the list than the window height (and thus no scrollbar), the list is always the correct width, and it always snaps to the correct width when you scroll to the top or bottom. It's only whilst the scrollbar is positioned somewhere inbetween that the width is wrong.

I've been wrestling with this problem all evening, trying various refactorings like using a DataTemplateSelector to abstract away the need for visibility bindings but I've ended up with really dirty workarounds I'm not happy with. I'd like to solve the actual problem at hand rather than dodge it. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

In the following example, the list appears to size itself to the width of both Foo and Bar. Changing the StackPanel orientation causes it to size to the width of whichever is longer out of Foo and Bar. Hope that makes sense.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Widgets}" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ShowFoo, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" Text="{Binding Foo}" />
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ShowBar, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisConverter}}" Text="{Binding Bar}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This effect what you're describing does not have to do with the visibility bindings.

> Essentially what I think is happening is that the ListBox calculates
>   the size of all it's children to determine it's own size, but only
>   seems to evaluate <s>visibility bindings for</s> controls that are actually
>   on the screen (presumably for performance reasons). The result is that
>   it calculates the size of it's off-screen children incorrectly,
>   reserving space for hidden controls.

This sounds correct to me. It's done for performance reasons. Also known as virtualization of `ListBox`. The other controls inherit this too, such as `DataGrid`.

In order to get rid of it, you can switch out `VirtualizingStackPanel` with the usual stackpanel:

```
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

You might, or might not suffer the performance penalty, if you have massive amount of items, but that's the life. If you do not like this, I suggest you not to have this requirement in the first place.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. That solved the problem immediately, thanks! I wish I'd asked four hours ago now because I was heading off in all sorts of dodgy directions with this one.